# Deleting specific files in a directory using bash

Tags: bash

I have a txt file with a list of files (approximately 500) for example:

```
file_0_hard.msOut
file_1_hard.msOut
file_10_hard.msOut
.
.
.
file_1000_hard.msOut
```

I want to delete all those files whose name is not in the txt file. All of these files are in the same directory. How can I do this using bash where I read the text file and then delete all those files in the directory that are not in the text file. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried something like `ls | grep -Fxvf list.txt | xargs echo rm`?

Comment: Yes. But it was taking a long time since I have to remove lots of files almost 300,000. So I figured maybe I should make a bash script and let it run on cluster.

Comment: I know I can do it in python using os.remove. But I wanted to know if there's a way to do it in bash.

Comment: The line I posted above is a shell command, it **is** *a way to do it in bash*

Comment: If speed is an issue, I don't think you can beat the solution proposed by @oguzismail, as long as you are doing it in bash. Even if you store each entry in your list into a bash array, then loop over all file names, and remove those which are not in the array, you have to do a separated `rm` for each file, i.e. create a child process, while `xargs` will invoke a single `rm` process for as many files as fit on the command line. It would be much faster if you write it in a language such as Python, Perl or Ruby, where you do can do everything in a single process.

Comment: Move all the files IN that file to another directory, then clean the directory and move them back.

Answer (score 0):

you may try this :

```
cd path/dir

for f in *; do
    if ! grep -Fxq "$f" pathToFile/file.txt; then
        rm -r "$f"
    else
        printf "exists-- %s \n" ${f}
    fi
done
```

In case you are wondering (as I did) what `-Fxq` means in plain English:

`F`: Affects how PATTERN is interpreted (fixed string instead of a regex)

`x`: Match whole line

`q`: Shhhhh... minimal printing

Comment: This would need **two** child processes for each file to be deleted in the directory. Considering the huge number of files, this is not practical, in particular since the solution proposed in the comment by Oguz Ismail is already too slow for the OP.

Comment: @user1934428 hmm then i will update with another solution, feel free to correct me

Comment: For that number of files, it is likely that your new version will produce an _arglist too long_ error.

Comment: Also, your solution may keep too many files. For instance, if `list.txt` contains an entry consisiting of the string `abcd`, and the file is named `bc`, it is not placed into `to_delete`. You would at least have to use the `-x` option in grep.

Comment: then I will remove the last one

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the directory in question is `mydir`

```
set -e
cd mydir
tmpdir=/tmp/x$$ # adapt this to your taste
mv $(<list.txt) $tmpdir
cd ..
rm -r mydir
mkdir mydir
mv $tmpdir/* mydir
rm -r $tmpdir
```

Basically, instead to delete those files you want to keep, you safe them, then delete everything, and then restore them. For your case, this is probably faster than doing the other way around.

**UPDATE**:

As `Michiel` commented, it is advisable that you place your tmpdir in the same file system as mydir.

Comment: @Michiel : How is this related to hard links? We don't do a `ln`. But of course the `mv` will be much faster, if `$tmpdir` is on the same file system. But even if it is not, if not only the number of the files to be kept is small compared to the number of the files to be deleted (which in fact is true as we know from the comment of the OP), but the size of the files to be kept is also small (which we don't know), moving the files might not be that bad. But I will edit my comment to point out the file system issue.

Comment: of course mv is faster; I first thought about a good use for hardlinks, but after that I realized mv does about the same. I want to find a good use for a hardlink :)

Comment: @Michiel : Maybe a good usage pattern is like holding object references to the same object in a programming language employing garbage collection: Several interested parties can have a hard link to a file and use the file and even delete it at will, but the file itself will going away only after the last one has removed the hard link. Kind of "reference counting at file-system level".

Answer (score 0):

Along the lines of user1934428

There is something to say for this solution. But since we have linux at our disposal with a strong filesystem in use I hope. we can make hardlinks; The only requirement for that the destination is on the same filesystem.

So along those lines:

- make a directory to store the files you want to keep.
- hardlink (ln {file} {target}) ; as this does not cost extra disk space, it only stores the inode number in the new directory file.
- remove all files
- move the files back from their origin.

And actually this would be about the same as:

- mv {files} {save spot}
- remove all files
- mv {save spot}/{files} back

Which does pretty much the same thing. Then again; it is a nice way to learn about the power of a hardlink.

Comment: I now get the point. Since the effect is the same as with the `mv` solution, is there an advantage of using `ln`, compared to just doing a `mv`?

Comment: hardly; you could look up if your saved files are complete. And I thought I finally found a good use for ln :)